# 一眼之念 一念执着 meaning

Tags: grammar, lyrics

I want to translate lyrics for 步步惊心 intro song.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vj8kElvozBY)

一眼之念 一念执着 - My Chinese friend told me that meaning is 
"I fall in love with you from first look"

一眼之念 - 1 look - I am missing. This is clear.

Can you explain second part? Are there some grammar rule for this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`一眼之念` is an imitation of the structure `一A之B`. The structure usually works in the way of `noun(B) of a noun(A)`:

```
一面之缘 Fate of an encounter
一饭之恩 Kindness of a meal-offering
一国之君 King of a nation
```

Personally I don't think `一眼之念` is a particularly good imitation. Because it would be interpreted as `Longing of one look`, and like the English expression I've used, it is similarly unidiomatic and ambiguous. However, it's pointless to blame a pop song for being ungrammatical, and it's easily understood if we put it into context.

`一念执着` is a shortened way of saying `一种执着的念想`. In English it would be `An obsessed longing` or we could use a coma and write `A longing, obsessed`. In Chinese it could also be `执着一念`. You asked about grammar, but in fact you can do all sorts of word play and ignore most of the grammatical restrictions in Chinese poems.

So to sum up:

> 一眼之念 A longing, result of one look
>
> 一念执着 A longing, obsessed

Not as beautiful as @NS.X.'s interpretation, but it might be closer to the original meaning.

Answer (score 2):

执着 means 'be attached to; stubbornly pursuit'. In the context of love affections it can be understood as 'obsession' or 'complex'.

> 一眼之念 It's just one look but I started longing.
>
> 一念执着 It's just one time of longing but it has become my obsession.